# Adobe Air works with hardcoded filePath, but fails when specifying filePath via command line

Tags: javascript, command-line, air, backbone.js

I don't know why this is. I'm using backbone with adobe air. If I hard code the filePath to the url attribute for backbone in adobe air, it works, but specifying it via command line doesn't work. I alerted the filePath and its the same full file path. Any clue?

Comment: Can you show us some code?  That can help us solve your problem.

Comment: Fixed it, the arguments passed was an array, which is wrongly thought of as a string.

Comment: Since someone else upvoted your question (probably wants to see a resolution), and you resolved the problem, you should probably add your changes/answer and click the 'checkmark' icon to show the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, the arguments passed was an array, which is wrongly thought of as a string.